# Rails - debugging functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am debugging a class which is structured like this

```
 class EmailQueue < ActiveRecord::Base
  logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER  

  def self.poll_mail
   logger.info "Running Mail Importer..." 
   ContactMailer.receive(email.pop)
 .........

class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'
 logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER

 def receive(email)
  logger.info "Processing Mail..."
 ..........
```

The debug messages in email queue are outputted but the messages in contactmailer are not outputted ?

ALex

Answer (score 0):

```
def recieve(email)
```

is an instance method, so maybe try changing to:

```
def self.receive(email)
```

or try instantiating like so

```
mailer = ContactMailer.new
mailer.recieve(email.pop)
```